# Display list views in a web part list

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, microsoft-lists, sharepoint-ootb

on a modern sharepoint page, i need to display differents views of my list. My list is customized in json with "hideselection:true"

For every view of my list, i created a web part list and configured it to display the choosen filtered view, and not to display the menu bar. So i have several web parts in my page

Question 1 : the differents views display well for me but not for users, they see the whole list in the webparts, not filtered. I cant explain why.

Question 2 : is there a way to create a menu in the page wich allow users to display dinamicly the wiew of their choice in a single web part list ?

Thanks if you have some directions to make me understand the point.

Comment: Hello, somebody to help me ? Im just stuck with this. Thxs